# Считать количество дней от сегодня до даты которую выбрал?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Хотел бы спросить какая у меня ошибка (но я не вижу ошибок в консоле) в моему подходу написания кода. 
Моя задача состоит в том, а именно:
считать количество дней от сегодня до даты которую выбрал

```css
var data1=new Date();
 new Vue({
  el: "#data-tag",
  data: {
   dataend: " ",
   datastart: " ",
   deadline: " ",
   milliseconds: "",
   seconds: "",
   minutes: "",
   hours: "",
   days: ""
  },
  methods: {
   Deadline() {
    this.datastart= new Date();
    this.deadline=Math.abs(this.dataend-this.datastart);

    this.milliseconds = this.deadline;
    this.seconds = this.milliseconds / 1000;
    this.minutes = this.seconds / 60;
    this.hours = this.minutes / 60;
    this.days = this.hours / 24;
    this.days=Math.ceil(days);
    console.log(this.days);
   }
  }
 })
```

```html
<div id="data-tag">
  <input type="date" placeholder="дата окончания" v-model="dataend">
  <div> {{days}}</div>
 </div>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не нужно столько свойств в data() для выполнения этой цели.
И в вашем скрипте вы по сути не запускали метод подсчета, в случае, который я привел ниже запускается метод при изменении свойства "dataend" , в watch я это отслеживаю и запускаю метод. Ниже прикрепил рабочий пример.

P.S. при присваивании `"this.days = abs/msPerDay"` можете округлить значения при помощи Math.round/ceil, как душе угодно)

```js
   new Vue({
el: "#data-tag",
data: {
  dataend: '',
  days: '',
},
watch: {
 dataend(){
   this.deadline();
 }
},
methods: {
 deadline() {
   const msPerDay = 8.64 * Math.pow(10, 7);
   const abs = Math.abs(Date.parse(this.dataend) - Date.now());
   this.days = abs/msPerDay;
 }
   }
 })
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="data-tag">
      <input type="date" placeholder="дата окончания" v-model="dataend">
      <div> {{days}}</div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

вы сильно усложняете.

```
Date.daysBetween = function( date1, date2 ) {
  //Get 1 day in milliseconds
  var one_day=1000*60*60*24;

  // Convert both dates to milliseconds
  var date1_ms = date1.getTime();
  var date2_ms = date2.getTime();

  // Calculate the difference in milliseconds
  var difference_ms = date2_ms - date1_ms;

  // Convert back to days and return
  return Math.round(difference_ms/one_day); 
}
```

Comment: я хочу именно на vue ))